# Ribbon button and client object model code

Tags: development, client-object-model, ribbon

My question is regarding the button on the ribbon and client object model code. I'm not sure how to do it:
So i have a button here:

```
<CustomAction Id="NewButton" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon" RegistrationId="103" RegistrationType="List">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.ListItem.Share.Controls._children">
          <Button
            Id="Ribbon.Documents.Share.Controls.NewButton"
            Sequence="5"
            Command="ShowAlert"
            Image16by16="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap16x16.png" Image16by16Top="-16" Image16by16Left="-88"
            Image32by32="/_layouts/$Resources:core,Language;/images/formatmap32x32.png" Image32by32Top="-128" Image32by32Left="-448"
            LabelText="$Resources:core,cui_ButEmailLink;"
            ToolTipTitle="$Resources:core,cui_ButEmailLink;"
            ToolTipDescription="$Resources:core,cui_STT_ButEmailLinkDocument;"
            TemplateAlias="o1" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler Command="ShowAlert" CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello world!');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
```

In this case it is just some simple java script: but i want to use more complex code, client side object model.
How to arrange that?

And directly another question in the code how can i check what kind of element is selected? like is it just an item or a document or a folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do more complex things with the ribbon I think its best to use a page component.

Waldek Mastykarz has written a nice [article](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-page-components-sandboxed-solutions/) with many links about using a page component.

But also [Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2011/10/my-ribbon-samples-from-spc11-session.html)  has written fine articles about complex code when using the ribbon.

Regarding your second question  you can use **get_fileSystemObjectType()** method on a selected item;

Answer (score 1):

I have written a series of blog posts about using SharePoint ribbon customizations here:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/search/label/Ribbon